# Creating a standard windows build environment using Windows Server Core and Vagrant

Tags: visual-studio-2013, jenkins, vagrant, server-core

I've created a command line build environment for windows through vagrant.  Basically want to be able to have a standard build environment that anyone in my team can bring up with using vagrant regardless of what machine they are on.

The environment runs on a Windows Server Core install.  Using the Chocolatey package manager to install cmake and visual studio.  When I run my provisioning script, it hangs, until I log into the windows core instance in VirtualBox.  Looks like until I see the visual studio 2013 splash screen, it blocks the install.

```
choco install visualstudiocommunity2013
```

I get the following in the vagrant log:

```
==> default: Installing the following packages:
==> default: 
==> default: visualstudiocommunity2013
==> default: By installing you accept licenses for the packages.
==> default: VisualStudioCommunity2013 v12.0.21005.1
==> default:  Downloading VisualStudioCommunity2013 32 bit
==> default: 
==> default:    from 'http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/1/B/71BA74D8-B9A0-4E6C-9159-A8335D54437E/vs_community.exe'
==> default:  Installing VisualStudioCommunity2013...
```

As soon I as see the splash screen, it completes the operation.  Anyone know if their is a way to suppress the splash screen. Ideally, I'd like my jenkins instance to use the same headless VM to run out continuous integration builds. Can't do that if someone has to see the splash screen.

Comment: did you try `choco install visualstudiocommunity2013 --confirm`?

Comment: Its working now.  Had to turn off confirmation: chocolatey feature enable -n=allowGlobalConfirmation.  Using --confirm would have probably worked too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frédéric had the right idea.  Had to confirm the package installation.  Easiest way to go is turn off confirmation all together by adding the following line before the installs:

```
chocolatey feature enable -n=allowGlobalConfirmation
```

Alternatively use --confirm on every package your installing.